# what does quotechar mean in mysql while importing data?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Someone sent me a `xlsx` excel file and I opened it with excel and saved as csv with utf8 encoding.

---

I use mysql workbench import wizard to **import an excel-made utf8 csv** file to a database table. But the imported result missed some data (less than it should have).

And I think it has something to do with the **quotechar**.

By default the **quotechar** is double quote but I have some data like this (mixing single quote and double quote):

- 8'10" foo bar
- 4" x 6" foo foo bar

I've try to omit the value but it can't (see the error from the pic).

So here I want to figure out:

1. What does **quotechar** mean here? How does it work? Why does it matter? Can't it just import everything from the csv file?
2. How can I import the data correctly while my data mixes single quote and double quote (later I need to retrieve them and use as search keywords, so it'd be better to keep the original form)?

[image]

my data looks like this in excel: 
[image]

Comment: Is your data [properly formatted](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) or is it badly formed? Normally any fields with quotes in them need additional quoting, like `8'10"` becomes `"8'10"""`. CSV is a really loose standard despite attempts to formalize it.

Comment: @tadman  I've addded a picture of my data viewed in Excel. But **additional quoting** is really new for me. Does it mean that I even need to add addtional quoting in excel? Someone sent me the data in xlsx and I simply saved as csv utf8.

Comment: Excel's pretty fast and loose with how it imports CSV and borders on freaky sometimes. It can handle situations that MySQL never will. Maybe you can save it back out from Excel in a standardized CSV format and then import that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to export your data from Excel as a CSV, I assume, so how this looks in Excel is irrelevant.

When you export the data from excel as a CSV format it's going to encapsulate your data in double quotes. Any double quotes in the data itself is going to be escaped by a second double quote automatically by excel.

As an example, if your data is:

```
 8"
```

When you export it will be:

```
 "8"""
```

You have to tell Mysql that you are enclosing strings in character `"`. That is the `quotechar` it's talking about. It's the second field on that form you are filling out.

I'm not sure how picky MySQl is going to be here since I haven't imported CSV to Mysql in forever and ever and ever. The trick with the Excel CSV output is that if you have data like:

```
8"
8'
```

It will output it as CSV:

```
"8"""
8'
```

The second record/field doesn't gain the double quote encapsulation since it doesn't contain a character that requires encapsulation (A double quote, a carriage return, or a line feed).

Mysql *might* choke on that second record (Hopefully it's import process is robust enough to handle encapsulated and non-encaps'd fields though)

Comment: Truly professional answer! It took me some time to fully understand your answer. Yes, I think it's the `8'` thing that caused some problems. See this [pic](https://imgur.com/RVyPClq). And I wonder why Excel do this **extra quoting work**  (I guess because any other databases all need the extra quotes to understand the inner quotes?  I've read this [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) about escape sequence) ? And since Excel quoted the double `"`, why doesn't it quoted the single quote `'`at the same time!?

Comment: Btw, I noticed that you said you would never ever import csv to mysql. How would you import excel data to a mysql table while avoiding these headache? Looking forward to your reply. ( •̀ ω •́ )y

Comment: Use a different delimiter (tab, pipe `|`, etc.). As I mentioned in the dba.stackexchange duplicate post...https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207509/what-does-quotechar-mean-in-mysql-while-importing-data :)

Comment: @JacobH But I think the `8'` problem has nothing to do with the delimiter. Btw, my data are all placed in 1 column, 1 piece of data for 1 row, no extra column.

Comment: @Rick My "Never, ever, ever" is that I just haven't done ETL from CSV into Mysql in FOREVER. Only because I tend to not work on mysql. I do ETL for a living, but it's in and out of SAP, Teradata, Oracle, SQL Server with lots of bash scripting, and vendor specific tools. CSV into mysql is totally 100% reasonable and I can't imagine a better way to get data into mysql.

Comment: As for using a different delimiter... that can get tricky with excel's very limited "Save As" options. You can consider using "Unicode Text" which will save as tab delimited. Excel will still use double quote encapsulation though to preserve your double quotes in your data, so it's really a wash. I think you'll be fine though exporting as csv in "Save As" and pointing MySQL at it, letting it know that you are encapsulating data in the `"` character. If that still doesn't work you can use VBA to output your excel data and gain more control.

Comment: Lastly, if this really becomes an issue (which is probably more due to Excel's limitations) you can use `awk` to scrub the encapsulation while preserving the data. `awk` is a whole other beast to learn though, so I would only pull out that hammer as a last ditch effort. And, yes I would agree that a delimiter isn't your issue, this is purely an encapsulation issue. It's also probably not an issue. Just set that thing to double quote `"` and hit the go button.

Comment: @JNevill thanks again. I am trying Mysql for Excel to see if it works. Btw, any idea why Excel not quoting the `8'` into `"8'"`? I tried the latter, it works.

Comment: @JNevill Excel Save As has a "Tab Delimited" option... it's the exact option above "Unicode Text"... I do a significant amount of data importing to SQL from Excel and I find CSV to be the least effective option. YMMV of course.

Comment: Right. That outputs tab delimited, but the delimiter isn't the issue here. The enscapsulation of the field in double quotes is. Perhaps tab delimited option doesn't encapsulate records containing double quotes or CRLF, but knowing excel, I'll bet it does. Regardless I think we have the problem solved as a standard CSV output, just setting up the mysql workbench/mysql import properly to OPTIONALLY deal with double quote field encaps.